# MySQL Update Trigger with Conditions

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, case

I have a PHP app that inserts 'Pass', 'Fail' or 'NA' into fields TEST1, TEST2, TEST3... through TEST15.

I have a field called OVERALL that needs to be automatically updated with 'FAIL' if any of the TEST1-TEST15 fields contains 'Fail'.

I'm pretty sure I need to use a trigger containing the update statement and either CASE or IF, but I haven't been able to nail down the exact syntax.

Can anyone please help a MySQL noob?  I'm using MySQL Server version: 5.1.63-0+squeeze1 (Debian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName AFTER INSERT ON yourTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.yourColumn = 'Fail' THEN
        UPDATE otherField set column = 'Fail'
    END IF;
END
```

This is what such a trigger could look like in theory, however I must say i'm not a 100% on the syntax since its been a while since i worked on mysql.

You can check the manual for more infos on the trigger
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you!

Would I need to use separate IF statements for each column I need to check, or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: If it's always the same column, you would update, then you can simply check all the columns with OR. For example: IF NEW.yourColumn = 'FAIL' OR NEW.otherColumn = 'FAIL', etc.. I hope it's clear what I mean.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I think I'm getting close!

I entered this at the mysql prompt:

`delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER setoverall AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_NAME

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF NEW.TEST1 = 'Fail' THEN
UPDATE TABLE_NAME set OVERALL = 'FAIL';
END IF;
END;
|

delimiter ;`

MySQL doesn't complain, but if I insert new data into TABLE_NAME, the OVERALL column doesn't get updated.
Any more clues?

Comment: I posted another answer with a modified trigger, makes it easier to read with the code highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is another TRIGGER you can give a try. I tested it and it should change the overall field to FAIL if either the value in test1 or test2 of the inserted row is FAIL. It will not set the overall-field for any other row besides the one you are inserting.

The code for the TRIGGER:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER setoverall BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.test1 = 'FAIL' OR NEW.test2 = 'FAIL' THEN
        SET NEW.overall = 'FAIL';
    END IF;
  END;
|
```

All you need to do is put in the correct table name and check all other 13 test-columns that you have in your table if their value is FAIL. I hope this helps you, if anything is unclear let me know.